# Interpolate across row NA's of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, interpolation, na, zoo

I have a dataframe with `NA` values peppered in that I want to interpolate.

Here is the repeatable example:

```
A <- as.data.frame(c(1:6))
A$b <- NA
A$c <- 2:7

library(zoo)
na.approx(A)

#expectation
A$b <- seq(1.5, 6.5, 1)
```

Obviously `na.approx()` isn't doing it for me, is there a function that will interpolate by row?

Comment: apply it row-wise , `t(apply(A, 1, na.approx))`

Comment: Note that doing things row-wise and/or using `apply` or `t` will result in the `data.frame` being converted to a `matrix`. In your example this is fine, but if there is any non-`numeric` in your data, this will have disastrous effects when all `numeric` data is converted to `character`.

Answer (score 6):

`na.approx` and also work column wise on a `matrix`

```
t(na.approx(t(A)))
```

Answer (score 3):

how about?

```
t(apply(A,1,na.approx));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution that enables you to keep the original data type:

```
library(imputeTS)
as.data.frame(t(na.interpolation(t(A))))
```

Will do the same calculation wise as the mentioned solutions with na.approx .
(but this way you'll still have a data.frame and retain your column names)